Mesh created with Geometry Nodes is slightly shifted compared to mesh created with XYZ Math Surface
I was trying to complete my answer for this question. I'm creating an XYZ Math Surface via Add > Mesh > Math Function > XYZ Math Surface using the following parametric equations:
X: (g*f)/16*(3/2*((u**2 + v**2)*(1 + (u + v - 1)**2) - 2*(u**2*v**2 - 2*(u*v - u - v) - 1))/(u**2 + u*v + v**2 - u - v + 1)**2) + (sqrt(3)/6*(3*u + 3*v - 2)/sqrt(u**2 + v**2 + u*v - u - v + 1))*f/2
Y: (g*f)/16*(3/2*sqrt(3)*((u**2 - v**2)*(1 + (u + v - 1)**2))/(u**2 + u*v + v**2 - u - v + 1)**2) - (1/2*(u - v)/sqrt(u**2 + v**2 + u*v - u - v + 1))*f/2
Z: (g*f)/16*(3/2*sqrt(2)*((u**2 + v**2)*(2 - (u + v - 1)**2) - (u**2*v**2 - 2*(u*v - u - v) - 1))/(u**2 + u*v + v**2 - u - v + 1)**2 - sqrt(2)) - (sqrt(6)/3*(-1)/sqrt(u**2 + u*v + v**2 - u - v + 1) - 1)*f/2

parameters:
U min:  0.00
U max:  1.00
U step: 72
V min:  0.00
V max:  1.00
V step: 72
F:  2.00
G: 0

Which look like this if I'm not mistaken:
$$
x(u,v) = \frac{g \cdot f}{16} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{(u^2 + v^2) \cdot (1 + (u + v - 1)^2) - 2 \cdot (u^2 \cdot v^2 - 2 \cdot (u \cdot v - u - v) - 1)}{(u^2 + u \cdot v + v^2 - u - v + 1)^2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} \cdot \frac{(3 \cdot u + 3 \cdot v - 2)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 + u \cdot v - u - v + 1}} \cdot \frac{f}{2}
$$
$$
y(u,v) = \frac{g \cdot f}{16} \left( \frac{3}{2} \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \frac{(u^2 - v^2) \cdot (1 + (u + v - 1)^2)}{(u^2 + u \cdot v + v^2 - u - v + 1)^2} \right) - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{(u - v)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 + u \cdot v - u - v + 1}} \cdot \frac{f}{2}
$$
$$
z(u,v) = \frac{g \cdot f}{16} \left( \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{(u^2 + v^2) \cdot \left(2 - (u + v - 1)^2\right) - \left(u^2 v^2 - 2 \cdot (u v - u - v) - 1\right)}{(u^2 + u v + v^2 - u - v + 1)^2} - \sqrt{2} \right) - \left( \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} \cdot \left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 + u v + v^2 - u - v + 1}} - 1 \right) \right) \cdot \frac{f}{2}
$$
When I try to map the nodes in a custom node group named XYZ-Surface, I get a surface that is lower on the z-axis. They should be coinciding with each other:

All the other surfaces I made worked perfectly except this one. Since it is the Z that is shifted, the problem must probably lie in the Z equation. However, no matter how many times I recheck the node tree, I can't understand why it's not positioned correctly. I have checked this several times now to no avail forcing me to seek for extra eyes to look at this.

Here's what's inside the main Geometry Nodes modifier:



It must be something very simple for sure but I just can't spot the error I made. EDIT: Maybe not as simple as I thought since I discovered I have the same shifted problem for the bottom surface.

Jeeeez .. this is hard labour! Your existing answer is heroic :)

Is there really no way to just write a function in Geometry Nodes? We need to use a separate node for every single instance of every mathematical operation? That makes debugging something like this SO difficult...

@RobinBetts thank you! it was a pain but nice learning experience too with the organizational part in GN! For Lawton: Yes currently you have to manually map the nodes but there are a lot of reusable parts. I could have also grouped some custom nodes into another bigger reusable custom node. There is an addon which allows you to input expressions but I'm not sure how usable this is. It's also already outdated, as its latest version is 3.1 https://blendermarket.com/products/node-expressions?search_id=30672263

@HarryMcKenzie Node Expressions  crossed my mind. I didn't realize it had been updated to include GN. It's by Rich Sedman, of this parish, who, (I'm sure he won't mind me saying,) has been a primary example for me to try to emulate, here on BSE. :)

@RobinBetts hey guys good news look what I've found. https://github.com/WannesMalfait/Blender-Add-ons/releases I was able to immediately copy all the python equations and paste them to instantly create the node tree. wow should have known this earlier and saved so much time XD

There is an error in transposing the equation from XYZ Math Surface code to LaTeX. The last part of $z(u,v)$, computed in the frame "Z Equation Term 2", is written as:
$$
z(u,v) = (...) - \left( \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} \cdot \left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 + u v + v^2 - u - v + 1}} - 1 \right) \right) \cdot \frac{f}{2}
$$
whereas it should be (from the pseudo-code):
$$
z(u,v) = (...) - \left( \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} \cdot \frac{-1}{\sqrt{u^2 + u v + v^2 - u - v + 1}} - 1 \right) \cdot \frac{f}{2}
$$
To debug, taking advantage that $g=0$, I specified $u=v=0$ for every grid point, yielding constant functions easier to track, after I noticed that the shift is almost the same at the four corners.

Side Note: I checked the rest and I could not find any mistake in the transposition. I did not checked the GN graph however... But after correction of the "Z Equation Term 2" frame, both surfaces are superimposed.

This is a video about Harry and Stef: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M61xXdVlP5o

oh my.. those parenthesis killed me lol. thank you so much! nice video btw! :D

A lesson in elegant debugging! Now I know there is such a thing :) @MarkusvonBroady :D great find! The copywriters earned their bucks, for once.
